# Why this simple UPDATE query can't work?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am very new to Microsoft SQL Server and I have a problem performing an `UPDATE` query:

I have a table named `VulnerabilityAlertDocument` that contains some columns.

If I try to update the value of a single column of a specific row using the following query I have no problem:

```
UPDATE VulnerabilityAlertDocument 
SET Title = 'UPDATED-TITLE' 
WHERE Id = '83157';
```

It works fine and the value of the `Title` column of the row having `Id=83157` is correctly changed to `UPDATED-TITLE`

But If I try to execute this new query that have to change also the value of another column named `BugTraqID` it doesn't work

```
UPDATE VulnerabilityAlertDocument 
SET BugTraqID = 1 
SET Title = 'UPDATED-TITLE' 
WHERE Id = '83157';
```

It can't work and give me the following error message:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.

What am I missing? Have I a syntax problem in my query? How can I solve it?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Removed mysql tag because question is explicitly about SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax for `update` uses a comma between set statements, not the `set` keyword:

```
UPDATE VulnerabilityAlertDocument
    SET BugTraqID = 1, 
        Title = 'UPDATED-TITLE'
    WHERE Id = '83157';
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to use `SET` once and then use commas to separate the columns to be updated:

```
UPDATE VulnerabilityAlertDocument 
SET BugTraqID = 1 
SET Title = 'UPDATED-TITLE' 
WHERE Id = '83157';
```

should be

```
UPDATE VulnerabilityAlertDocument 
SET BugTraqID = 1, 
Title = 'UPDATED-TITLE' 
WHERE Id = '83157';
```